# *** glibc detected *** /usr/sbin/apache2: free(): invalid pointer

Tags: glibc, apache2.2, php-5.6

I have a problem in apache2 when I restart Apache, the CPU freezes and log become huge every time someone visit pages.

My `Debian` version is `wheezy 7.1`.

What it seems to be the problem?

This is my config :

**Apache 2**

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server built:   Dec 23 2014     
22:48:29 Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:30  
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.6, APR-Util 1.4.1  
Compiled using: APR 1.4.6, APR-Util 1.4.1  
Architecture:   64-bit   
Server MPM:     Prefork   
threaded:     no    
forked:     yes (variable process count)
```

Server compiled with

```
-D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"   
-D APR_HAS_SENDFILE  
-D APR_HAS_MMAP  
-D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)  
-D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE  
-D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE  
-D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD  
-D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS  
-D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128   
-D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"  
-D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"  
-D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"   
-D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"  
-D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="/var/run/apache2/accept.lock"  
-D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"  
-D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"  
-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

**PHP5 Config**

```
PHP 5.6.6-1~dotdeb.1 (cli) (built: Feb 20 2015 19:57:36)  
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group  
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies with Zend 
OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
```

Here is the log

```
*** glibc detected *** /usr/sbin/apache2: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f14c85feaf8 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x75be6)[0x7f14e42c3be6]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6c)[0x7f14e42c898c]
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so(php_module_shutdown+0x2b)[0x7f14e0f1b81b]
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so(php_module_shutdown_wrapper+0x9)[0x7f14e0f1b8d9]
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so(+0x44d551)[0x7f14e1023551]
/usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0(apr_pool_destroy+0x7e)[0x7f14e480f99e]
/usr/sbin/apache2(+0x5bece)[0x7f14e5105ece]
/usr/sbin/apache2(+0x5c33e)[0x7f14e510633e]
/usr/sbin/apache2(+0x5c942)[0x7f14e5106942]
/usr/sbin/apache2(ap_mpm_run+0x9d6)[0x7f14e51074a6]
/usr/sbin/apache2(main+0xc26)[0x7f14e50db8e6]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x7f14e426cead]
/usr/sbin/apache2(+0x31981)[0x7f14e50db981]
======= Memory map: ========
7f14c8491000-7f14d0491000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 2397454                    /dev/zero (deleted)
7f14d0491000-7f14d0492000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f14d0492000-7f14d0c92000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f14d8000000-7f14d8021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f14d8021000-7f14dc000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f14dc62e000-7f14dc632000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4070055                   /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_status.so
7f14dc632000-7f14dc832000 ---p 00004000 08:01 4070055                    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_status.so
7f14dc832000-7f14dc833000 r--p 00004000 08:01 4070055                    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_status.so
7f14dc833000-7f14dc834000 rw-p 00005000 08:01 4070055                    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_status.so
7f14dc834000-7f14dc837000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4070024                    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_setenvif.so
7f14dc837000-7f14dca36000 ---p 00003000 08:01 4070024                    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_setenvif.so
7f14dca36000-7f14dca37000 r--p 00002000 08:01 4070024                    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_setenvif.so
7f14dca37000-7f14dca38000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 4070024                    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_setenvif.so
7f14dca38000-7f14dca4b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f14dca4b000-7f14dca56000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1969681                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
7f14dca56000-7f14dcc55000 ---p 0000b000 08:01 1969681                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
7f14dcc55000-7f14dcc56000 r--p 0000a000 08:01 1969681                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
7f14dcc56000-7f14dcc57000 rw-p 0000b000 08:01 1969681                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
7f14dcc57000-7f14dcc61000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1969691                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.13.so
7f14dcc61000-7f14dce60000 ---p 0000a000 08:01 1969691                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.13.so
7f14dce60000-7f14dce61000 r--p 00009000 08:01 1969691                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.13.so
7f14dce61000-7f14dce62000 rw-p 0000a000 08:01 1969691                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.13.so
7f14dce62000-7f14dce69000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1969695                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.13.so
7f14dce69000-7f14dd068000 ---p 00007000 08:01 1969695                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.13.so
7f14dd068000-7f14dd069000 r--p 00006000 08:01 1969695                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.13.so
7f14dd069000-7f14dd06a000 rw-p 00007000 08:01 1969695                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.13.so
7f14dd24b000-7f14dd25a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4070047                    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
7f14dd25a000-7f14dd459000 ---p 0000f000 08:01 4070047                    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
7f14dd459000-7f14dd45a000 r--p 0000e000 08:01 4070047                    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
7f14dd45a000-7f14dd45b000 rw-p 0000f000 08:01 4070047                    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
7f14dd45b000-7f14dd45e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4070011                    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
7f14dd45e000-7f14dd65d000 ---p 00003000 08:01 4070011                    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
7f14dd65d000-7f14dd65e000 r--p 00002000 08:01 4070011                    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
7f14dd65e000-7f14dd65f000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 4070011                    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
7f14dd65f000-7f14dd666000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4070053                    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
7f14dd666000-7f14dd866000 ---p 00007000 08:01 4070053                    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
7f14dd866000-7f14dd867000 r--p 00007000 08:01 4070053                    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
7f14dd867000-7f14dd868000 rw-p 00008000 08:01 4070053                    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
7f14dd868000-7f14dd87c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4070012                    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
7f14dd87c000-7f14dda7b000 ---p 00014000 08:01 4070012                    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
7f14dda7b000-7f14dda7c000 r--p 00013000 08:01 4070012                    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
7f14dda7c000-7f14dda7d000 rw-p 00014000 08:01 4070012                    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
7f14dda7d000-7f14dda90000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1969699                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.13.so
7f14dda90000-7f14ddc8f000 ---p 00013000 08:01 1969699                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.13.so
7f14ddc8f000-7f14ddc90000 r--p 00012000 08:01 1969699                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.13.so
7f14ddc90000-7f14ddc91000 rw-p 00013000 08:01 1969699                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.13.so
7f14ddc91000-7f14ddc93000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f14ddc93000-7f14ddc96000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1966561                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1.4
7f14ddc96000-7f14dde95000 ---p 00003000 08:01 1966561                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1.4
7f14dde95000-7f14dde96000 r--p 00002000 08:01 1966561                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1.4
7f14dde96000-7f14dde97000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 1966561                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1.4
7f14dde97000-7f14dde9f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3805273                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7f14dde9f000-7f14de09e000 ---p 00008000 08:01 3805273                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7f14de09e000-7f14de09f000 r--p 00007000 08:01 3805273                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7f14de09f000-7f14de0a0000 rw-p 00008000 08:01 3805273                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7f14de0a0000-7f14de0c2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1966120                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7f14de0c2000-7f14de2c1000 ---p 00022000 08:01 1966120                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7f14de2c1000-7f14de2c2000 r--p 00021000 08:01 1966120                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7f14de2c2000-7f14de2c3000 rw-p 00022000 08:01 1966120                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
.......
7f14e50a8000-7f14e50a9000 rw-p 00020000 08:01 1969698                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
7f14e50a9000-7f14e50aa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f14e50aa000-7f14e511c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4069997                    /usr/lib/apache2/mpm-prefork/apache2
7f14e531b000-7f14e531d000 r--p 00071000 08:01 4069997                    /usr/lib/apache2/mpm-prefork/apache2
7f14e531d000-7f14e5321000 rw-p 00073000 08:01 4069997                    /usr/lib/apache2/mpm-prefork/apache2
7f14e5321000-7f14e5325000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f14e5345000-7f14e5366000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7f14e5366000-7f14e580b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7ffffaa31000-7ffffaa52000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffffab5e000-7ffffab5f000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
[Thu Jul 30 11:44:56 2015] [notice] child pid 8372 exit signal Aborted (6)                                      
7f14e531d000-7f14e5321000 rw-p 00073000 08:01 4069997                    /usr/lib/apache2/mpm-prefork/apache2
7f14e5321000-7f14e5325000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f14e5345000-7f14e5366000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7f14e5366000-7f14e580b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7ffffaa31000-7ffffaa52000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffffab5e000-7ffffab5f000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
[Thu Jul 30 11:44:56 2015] [notice] child pid 8372 exit signal Aborted (6)
```

Answer (score 2):

Issue fixed
I use to load two times Zend Opcache.
Thank you for fixing my grammar and syntax mistakes.